# Columns in Dynamic partitioning in Hive

Tags: dynamic, hive, partitioning

In dynamic partitioning in Hive, suppose we want to partition a column which is there in the middle of the table, we must be creating a new table and then reordering the columns to get the column which is to be partitioned in the last.
Is it really fine if we do this on the cluster where we get huge data?

Comment: So, if your question was actually *"when we want to partition an existing, non-partitioned table, we must re-create a new table"* then the answer is Yes. If your question was *"dude, we must write down the list of columns and their types in the CREATE AS SELECT script, it's too much work"* then the answer is Yes, What A Pity.

Comment: And finally, if the question was actually *"we should have designed a partitioned table to begin with, shouldn't we"* then the answer is Yes, But You Cannot Always Win On First Attempt.